# python regex line matching

Tags: python, regex

I'm quite new to python and would like some help.

I have a file called pdu.tmp containing lines like :

Foldername;PDU-8000;location: ;172.27.0.69
Foldername;PDU-A8009;location: ;172.27.0.64
Foldername;PDU-A8091;location: ;172.27.0.48
...

I would like to match lines containing PDU- and print them to the screen

My problem is my regex don't seem to match (I always get None) even when I make the regex simple using .*
I tried to strip my "line" because there seemed to be a newline when I printed "line" in itself. But that didn't fix it either

this is my code :

#### START

```
import re

p = re.compile(r"""
Foldername.*            
,NULL
""", re.VERBOSE)

i = 0

output = open('pdu.temp', 'r')

for line in output:
    newline = line.strip() # stripped the line here
    print newline
    m = p.match(newline)
    print m
    if m:
        print "Until now I found " + str(i) + "matches" + '\n'
    #   print i + ":" + line
        i += 1

output.close()
```

#### END

Here the output after running the script :

```
Foldername;Contact Name;location: Location;IP Address
None
Foldername;PDU-A8094;location: ;172.27.0.44
None
Foldername;PDU-A8011;location: ;172.27.0.56
None
Foldername;PDU-8000;location: ;172.27.0.69
None
Foldername;PDU-A8009;location: ;172.27.0.64
None
Foldername;PDU-A8091;location: ;172.27.0.48
```

help in making me understand how to debug this would be great !

Comment: I think the script is clear no, the input is the file output I opened . pdu.temp contains lines that are shown in the print m :

Foldername;PDU-A8094;location: ;172.27.0.44

Comment: I just want lines containing PDU- to be filtered out of pdu.tmp and print it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what you want to achive, try posting example output.

But maybe this will match it as you want?

```
import re
p = re.compile(r'Foldername;(.*);location: (.*);(.*)')
i = 0
with open('input.txt', 'r') as input:
    for line in input:
        m = p.match(line)
        if m:
            print "Until now I found " + str(i) + " matches" + '\n'
        #   print i + ":" + line
            i += 1
```

And if it is what you want consider changing

```
if m:
    print "Until now I found " + str(i) + " matches" + '\n'
    i += 1
```

to

```
if m:
    i += 1
    print "Until now I found " + str(i) + " matches" + '\n'
```

to avoid 0 at output.
My input.txt file contains:

```
Foldername;Contact Name;location: Location;IP Address
None
Foldername;PDU-A8094;location: ;172.27.0.44
None
Foldername;PDU-A8011;location: ;172.27.0.56
None
Foldername;PDU-8000;location: ;172.27.0.69
None
Foldername;PDU-A8009;location: ;172.27.0.64
None
Foldername;PDU-A8091;location: ;172.27.0.48
```

Comment: "Until now I found 0 matches" is correct for the first output.

Comment: @James Buck: It's in `if m:` so I think it is printed after first match, or am I wrong?

Comment: Yes it's printed during the first match, but it's correct to assume that no matches were found until the first match. ie. this is the first time the code has entered the `if m` block - until now it had not been entered.

Comment: @James Buck: I think it's a matter of interpretation now. You can be right about that :)

Answer (score 0):

1. Your regex does not match as NULL appears nowhere in your text.
2. i is not initialised anywhere in your code.

Instead you should try:

```
from __future__ import print_statement

import re

p = re.compile(r"""
^
Foldername;PDU
""", re.VERBOSE)

output = open('pdu.temp', 'r')

i = 0;
for line in output:
    newline = line.strip() # stripped the line here
    m = p.match(newline)
    if m:
        print("Until now I found " + str(i) + " matches")
        i += 1
        print('{0}:{1}\n'.format(i, line))
```

[Demo here](http://repl.it/yrI/2).

Note that `from __future__ import print_statement` is included so the same code works in Python 2.7 and Python 3.x.

Comment: sorry guys, I forgot to put i in the code while pasting and editing the code to put it here.
I am trying to match lines containing PDU- from pdu.tmp and print them to the screen. Should have been clearer.

Comment: thx that did the trick, so silly of me... I copied that REGEX from another script ! And thought it was some kind of regex option... mea culpa

Comment: @bennethos Ok that's good except you accepted the other answer. Please consider accepting this answer instead if it fixed your problem.